ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Not always printing all active sheets
have 2 Subs that do the exact same thing, but for different Worksheets.
Unhide 7 sheets, select all, print, hide them all.
Sub PrintStage2() works as expected and exports all selected worksheets.
Sub PrintStage1() won't print the last worksheet ("S1 ELT Comments")
"S1 ELT Comments" is an exact copy of "S2 ELT Comments" just with a rename. (inc all page print settings)
Can anyone suggest anything I can look into.
Excel Version: Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2409 Build 16.0.18025.20030) 64-bit
Sub PrintStage1()

Dim S1ProjectName As String
Dim ary As String
Dim strTimeStamp1 As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Application.EnableEvents = False

'Create dateStamp
strTimeStamp1 = Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd")

Sheets("S1 Project Leader").Visible = True
Sheets("S1 Risk Summary").Visible = True
Sheets("S1 Financials").Visible = True
Sheets("S1 Appendices").Visible = True
Sheets("S1 ELT Comments").Visible = True
Sheets("G1 DASHBOARD P1").Visible = True
Sheets("G1 DASHBOARD P2").Visible = True

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("G1 DASHBOARD P1", _
  "G1 DASHBOARD P2", _
  "S1 Project Leader", _
  "S1 Risk Summary", _
  "S1 Financials", _
  "S1 Appendices", _
  "S1 ELT Comments")).Select

S1ProjectName = Range("S1_Value_ProjectName")

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
  Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:= _
  "C:\Temp\GatePapers\" & S1ProjectName & " - Gate 1 " & strTimeStamp1, _
  Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
  IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
  IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
  OpenAfterPublish:=True

Worksheets("HOME").Activate

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> ActiveSheet.Name Then ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Next ws
End Sub

Sub PrintStage2()

Dim S2ProjectName As String
Dim ary As String
Dim strTimeStamp2 As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Application.EnableEvents = False

'Create dateStamp
strTimeStamp2 = Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd")


Sheets("S2 Project Leader").Visible = True
Sheets("S2 Risk Summary").Visible = True
Sheets("S2 Financials").Visible = True
Sheets("S2 Appendices").Visible = True
Sheets("S2 ELT Comments").Visible = True
Sheets("G2 DASHBOARD P1").Visible = True
Sheets("G2 DASHBOARD P2").Visible = True



ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("G2 DASHBOARD P1", _
  "G2 DASHBOARD P2", _
  "S2 Project Leader", _
  "S2 Risk Summary", _
  "S2 Financials", _
  "S2 Appendices", _
  "S2 ELT Comments")).Select


S2ProjectName = Range("S2_Value_ProjectName")

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
  Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:= _
  "C:\Temp\GatePapers\" & S2ProjectName & " - Gate 2 " & strTimeStamp2, _
  Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
  IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
  IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
  OpenAfterPublish:=True


Worksheets("HOME").Activate

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> ActiveSheet.Name Then ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Next ws


End Sub

Tried

removing sheets from PrintStage1
Tried deleting "S1 ELT Comments" and duplicating "S2 ELT Comments" and using that in PrintStage1
tried many different print settings.
tried with file linked to sharepoint
tried with file saved locally and not syncing with cloud.

Expecting:

PrintStage1 to generate a PDF with all active worksheets.


Works perfectly fine for me, there are no issues with the code (apart from the fact that it could be improved) but it seems to be working fine.

Just some observations: The order of the sheets is different when you're hiding than when you're printing. Is the order when printing satisfactory? Are all these sheets worksheets (not charts)? You are being somewhat inconsistent about them: you are not qualifying them with the correct workbook when unhiding, then you are doing it correctly when printing but using the Sheets collection and finally doing it correctly when hiding but using the Worksheets collection also including any other worksheet that is not named Home, the name of another unqualified worksheet.

Export to PDF

Not sure if this will fix your issue but it's a step closer to figuring out what's happening. Repeatedly writing (copying) the same code and applying a few changes in various places of the code is prone to typos.
Let us know in the comments below if this works or at least you have confirmed that the relevant sheet exists and is visible (see the comment starting with "Here...").

The Calls
Sub PrintStage1()
    PrintStage 1
End Sub

Sub PrintStage2()
    PrintStage 2
End Sub

Main
Sub PrintStage(ByVal ProjectID As Long)

    ' Define constants.
    Const PROJECT_ID_PLACE_HOLDER As String = "XX"
    Const FOLDER_PATH As String = "C:\Temp\GatePapers\"
    Const PROJECT_CELL_NAME As String = "SXX_Value_ProjectName"
    Const PROJECT_NAME_LEFT_MID_DELIMITER As String = " - "
    Const PROJECT_NAME_MID As String = "Gate XX"
    Const PROJECT_NAME_MID_DATE_DELIMITER As String = " "
    Const DATE_FORMAT As String = "yyyy-mm-dd"
    Const FILE_EXTENSION As String = ".pdf"
    Const MAIN_SHEET_NAME As String = "HOME"
    Dim SheetNames() As Variant: SheetNames = VBA.Array( _
        "GXX DASHBOARD P1", _
        "GXX DASHBOARD P2", _
        "SXX Project Leader", _
        "SXX Risk Summary", _
        "SXX Financials", _
        "SXX Appendices", _
        "SXX ELT Comments")
    
    ' Reference the workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Build the file path.
    Dim ProjectCellName As String: ProjectCellName = Replace( _
        PROJECT_CELL_NAME, PROJECT_ID_PLACE_HOLDER, ProjectID)
    Dim FileNameLeft As String:
    FileNameLeft = wb.Names(ProjectCellName).RefersToRange.Value
    Dim DateString As String: DateString = Format(Date, DATE_FORMAT)
    Dim ProjectNameMid As String: ProjectNameMid = Replace( _
        PROJECT_NAME_MID, PROJECT_ID_PLACE_HOLDER, ProjectID)
    Dim FilePath As String: FilePath = FOLDER_PATH & FileNameLeft _
        & PROJECT_NAME_LEFT_MID_DELIMITER & ProjectNameMid _
        & PROJECT_NAME_MID_DATE_DELIMITER & DateString & FILE_EXTENSION
    'Debug.Print FilePath
    
    ' Replace the Project ID place holders with the Project ID.
    Dim SheetsUpper As Long: SheetsUpper = UBound(SheetNames)
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 0 To SheetsUpper
        SheetNames(n) = Replace( _
            SheetNames(n), PROJECT_ID_PLACE_HOLDER, ProjectID)
        'Debug.Print SheetNames(n)
    Next n
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Unhide the sheets.
    For n = 0 To SheetsUpper
        wb.Worksheets(SheetNames(n)).Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Next n
    
    ' Here you can check if the sheet exists and becomes visible.
    'If ProjectID = 1 Then CheckComments1: Exit Sub
    ' Remove this if the message confirms it's visible!
    
    ' Export the sheets to PDF.
    wb.Activate
    wb.Worksheets(SheetNames).Select
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=FilePath, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True
    
    ' Hide the sheets.
    For n = 0 To SheetsUpper
        wb.Worksheets(SheetNames(n)).Visible = xlSheetHidden
    Next n
    
    ' Select the main sheet.
    wb.Sheets(MAIN_SHEET_NAME).Select
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Help
Sub CheckComments1()
    
    Const SHEET_NAME As String = "S1 ELT Comments"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SHEET_NAME)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If ws Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "There is no sheet named """ & SHEET_NAME & """!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim sVisible As String:
    
    Select Case ws.Visible
        Case xlSheetVisible: sVisible = "visible"
        Case xlSheetHidden: sVisible = "hidden"
        Case xlSheetVeryHidden: sVisible = "very hidden"
    End Select
    
    MsgBox "Sheet """ & SHEET_NAME & """ is " & sVisible & ".", vbInformation
    
End Sub


Hi VBasic2008,
Thank you for the detailed trouble shooting.
Unfortunately, this hasn't resolved anything, but did lead me to do more trouble shooting.


If I remove other sheets and add them in one at a time;  "S1 ELT Comments" works when combined with the first 3, but not with any of the other 3.


I also tried using "S2 Comments" instead of "S1 Comments"  when printing PrintStage1 and S2 Comments didn't print.


So this is leading me to believe that the issue is something to do with worksheets Risk, Financials and Appendices.

So this issue is not actually related to the VBA at all. So I'm going to mark this solved.  I still don't have the full answer and will continue to try and debug,  but basically if I select worksheets
Test 1

G1 DASHBOARD P1
G1 DASHBOARD P2
S1 Project Leader
S1 Risk Summary
S1 Financials
S1 Appendices
S1 ELT Comments

And then just do a normal print, S1 ELT Comments isn't include
Test 2

S1 Project Leader
S1 ELT Comments

Comments work
Test 3

S1 Project Leader
S1 Risk Summary
S1 ELT Comments

Comments don't work
Test 4

S1 Risk Summary
S1 ELT Comments

Comments work.
Conclusion
after a few others tests as well it appears that if S1 Project Leader is select with either Risk, Financials or Appendices, then Comments doesn't work.
